# Return object as an argument

Tags: php, oop, object, methods

Is best practise to return an object as an argument??
More specific which of the following implementatios considered better?

a)

```
$foo = new ClassAInstance();
$bar = new ClassBInstance();

$bar->doSomethingToFoo($foo);
```

b)

```
$foo = new ClassAInstance();
$bar = new ClassBInstance();

$foo = bar->doSomethingToFoo($foo);
```

The example was too dump.Hope you understand the general concept of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. Both are technically correct, but are not perfectly object-oriented. I think the real problem is that the state of foo changes, because of $bar. This means the function might have at least two purposes.

It seems better to let an object change its own state, instead of another object changing the state of foo. For example:

```
$foo->changeState($bar->calculateValue($foo));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `doSomethingToFoo($someObject)` is responsible for changing passed object properties, then there's no need to return the changed object back to client code (it would be a redundant way). 
When an object is sent by argument, that argument is a pointer to the original object. Thus, your function will effect the original object directly.
Consider the following example:

```
class ClassA {
    public $name;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

class ClassB {
    function doSomethingWithObject($obj){
        $obj->name = "changed name";
    } 
}

$foo = new ClassA("John");
echo $foo->name;   // "John"

$bar = new ClassB();
$bar->doSomethingWithObject($foo);

echo $foo->name;   // "changed name"
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: With your way it is not so obvious to the reader which part of your code change the state of `$foo`. Something that make your code hard for debugging.

Comment: @dios231, I have presented a very simple example. If you have difficulty with such simple things, you should start read some books before debugging. At least, you should read this article: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php, though, it won't be enough

Comment: probably you misunderstood my previous mention. I did not want to insult neither your code or you, peace. My main concept is that in a large-scale app where in a single module will be more tha 100 method calls, will not be so obvious when an object change state. Lets say you have 4 methods in raw that take $foo as parameter. How can the reader know in which method the object change his state, in a simple way without having to take double-takes?

Comment: to "capture" the event of subject's state change - consider using the Observer pattern. https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer/php